# SQL Complex calculation and updating bulk records

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider the below scenario,

I am having 
Table A,
Table B and
Table C.

In these above tables needs to get updated their records as per calculation formula in respective columns on regular time interval. 
(For example 24 hours once.)

So I tried in stored procedure and made in job scheduler by writing the queries to update the records.

When I am executing the procedure , it is taking 15 to 20 minutes to execute and complete SQL Server management studio getting hanged because of 5000 records in each table.

So I splitted the updation process into 3 seperate procedures and noted the time for execution as 1 minute for each procedure based on count of records.

Even After optimization of the procedure,

1. What kind of transaction needs to provide for updating the data for avoiding exceptions?
2. Is there any other possibility to retain the server from timeout issue?

**My DB Plan Information:**

I am developing Rental systems product. 
In that Room Information will be available in a table 1. 
Rented Customer Information will be available in table 2.
Rented room and its tenant invoice will be available in table 3
Rented room and its tenant receipt will be available in table 4

Step 1  : Need to calculate total due amount for all tenant, Dues in days,Dues in months for each invoice in a while loop for updating in the table records.

Step 2  : Need to calculate total late fee for each invoice on regular basis.
(Note: Late fee will vary based on per day calculation basis for same invoice.)

So I am storing into table 5 as common table for all leases with their respective calculated value on daily basis. 
For that I have created a common stored procedure for calculating all data and Based on user defined function, It will update into table 5.

I am fetching from table 5 to all my reports and grid.

Problem statement:
Even I have optimized the procedure, When I am executing it, It is taking around 150 seconds approximately.

Question : How can I implement transaction for this action and How to make it in proper way by avoiding any deadlocks and other's data in the same table has to get accessed at the same time ?

Comment: Do you need to update all of the records each time? If you need to update the records who has changed, after the last update, you can add date time column like "LastModifiedOn". Then you can update only these records which has "LastModifiedOn" date bigger then the last update.

Comment: I am having last modified column, based on that It has to run daily basis to update the records

Comment: please show us your stored procedure, 5000 records is not consider huge at all. Please also explain what the stored procedure is doing

Comment: I am preparing the schema information and let you know once done..

Comment: I have edited my question and elaborated my requirement. Please let me know any other information needed. so that I can provide you.

Answer (score 0):

you can go to the below link to change the timeout session for your SQL server management studio

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-query-timeout-server-configuration-option

And I suggest you keep your drive space free as much as you as can by compressing your ldf and mdf files.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using cursor i have this suggestion

try change it to join (if its possible)

if you are using "transaction" and its out of your cursor and if its not  damage your data try to bring it into the  cursor and  commit in cursor not after ending your query